# Getting listing of files in split-volume 7zip archive

Tags: windows-10, 7-zip, directory-listing, multi-volume

I'm using the following command to create a multi-part (each 1G) 7zip archive under Windows 10 (basically a full backup of my documents area):

```
7z a -r -v1g -bb -y \path\to\zips\xyzzy.7z .
```

This successfully creates about 38 1G files for me. However, I wanted to get a listing of all files in the archive afterwards and I'm stumped as to how to do this. The command:

```
7z l xyzzy.7z.001
```

returns an error:

```
7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 1073741824 bytes (1024 MiB)

Listing archive: \somewhere\xyzzy.7z.001

--
Path = \somewhere\xyzzy.7z.001
Type = Split
Physical Size = 1073741824
Volumes = 1
Total Physical Size = 1073741824

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
                    .....   1073741824   1073741824  xyzzy.7z
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
                            1073741824   1073741824  1 files
----------
Path = xyzzy.7z
Open ERROR: Can not open the file as [7z] archive

Errors: 1
```

So the underlying `7z` file appears to be visible within the `.7z.001` file but it's complaining that it's not a valid archive.

I've also tried it with the `-tsplit` which removed the error but only then shows the contents as `xyzzy.7z` without delving in to that file to see its content. In other words, the output is identical to that above but the final line is the one ending `1 files`.

Why is this the case? Have I got the command-line parameters wrong? How do I get a file listing out of the split archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use the drive letter on the path to the 7-zip file. For example:

```
7z l C:\somewhere\xyzzy.7z.001
```

It seems to be a bug in version 16.02. I did the following tests:

```
E:\temp>7za l \temp\archive.7z.001

7-Zip (a) [32] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 1048576 bytes (1024 KiB)

Listing archive: \temp\archive.7z.001

--
Path = \temp\archive.7z.001
Type = Split
Physical Size = 1048576
Volumes = 1
Total Physical Size = 1048576

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
                    .....      1048576      1048576  archive.7z
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
                               1048576      1048576  1 files
----------
Path = archive.7z
Open ERROR: Can not open the file as [7z] archive

Errors: 1

E:\temp>7za l E:\temp\archive.7z.001

7-Zip (a) [32] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 1048576 bytes (1024 KiB)

Listing archive: E:\temp\archive.7z.001

--
Path = E:\temp\archive.7z.001
Type = Split
Physical Size = 1048576
Volumes = 6
Total Physical Size = 5533143
----
Path = archive.7z
Size = 5533143
--
Path = archive.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 5533143
Headers Size = 170
Method = LZMA2:6m
Solid = -
Blocks = 1

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2013-03-13 09:23:44 ....A      6010800      5532973  gotingeno-davideosendacommon.pdf
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2013-03-13 09:23:44            6010800      5532973  1 files

------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2013-03-13 09:23:44            6010800      5532973  1 files

Archives: 1
Volumes: 6
Total archives size: 5533143

E:\temp>7za l archive.7z.001

7-Zip (a) [32] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 1048576 bytes (1024 KiB)

Listing archive: archive.7z.001

--
Path = archive.7z.001
Type = Split
Physical Size = 1048576
Volumes = 6
Total Physical Size = 5533143
----
Path = archive.7z
Size = 5533143
--
Path = archive.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 5533143
Headers Size = 170
Method = LZMA2:6m
Solid = -
Blocks = 1

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2013-03-13 09:23:44 ....A      6010800      5532973  gotingeno-davideosendacommon.pdf
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2013-03-13 09:23:44            6010800      5532973  1 files

------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2013-03-13 09:23:44            6010800      5532973  1 files

Archives: 1
Volumes: 6
Total archives size: 5533143
```

Comment: So, based on your test output, it appears to work with either a full-path, `e:\somewhere\something.7z.001`, or a file-name-only if you're already in the correct directory, `something.7z.001`. That's very weird (but I suppose many bugs are). In any case, I'll try these when I get to the computer in question later today.

Comment: Well, we have a winner, bizarre though that behaviour is. The difference between failure and success is the presence of the drive letter. Thanks for your help.